# how to filter record from jqGrid using html dropdown using id

Tags: jqgrid, jqgrid-asp.net, mvcjqgrid

i am using jqgrid and i am to filter record from combo data is loaded from database .[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mPq66.png)

Screen 1
Controler

```
public JsonResult Getlist(int id,int LstatusId, bool AllDate,string DateFrom,string DateTo)
        {
            List<leadMaster> lmasterRecords = new List<leadMaster>();
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constring))
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SP_leadMasterDetail", con))
                {
                    if (clsCommon._UserType == "A")
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AgentID", id);
                    else
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AgentID", clsCommon._AgentID);

                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LeadStatusID",LstatusId);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AllDates",AllDate);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateFrom",DateFrom);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateTo",DateTo);

                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    con.Open();
                    SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        lmasterRecords.Add(
                            new leadMaster
                            {

                                RecordID = Convert.ToInt64(reader.GetValue(0)),
                                Name = reader.GetString(1),
                                CityName = reader.GetString(2),
                                CountryName=reader.GetString(3),
                                Address=reader.GetString(4),
                                PhoneNo=reader.GetString(5),
                                MobileNo=reader.GetString(6),
                                Email=reader.GetString(7),
                                EnteryDate = reader.GetDateTime(8).ToShortDateString(),
                                ProfType=reader.GetString(9),
                                LeadStatus=reader.GetString(10),
                                ProjName=reader.GetString(11),
                                UnitTypeName=reader.GetString(12),
                                Description=reader.GetString(13),
                                User_name=reader.GetString(14),
                                IsClose=reader.GetString(15)


                            }
                        );
                    }
                }
            }

            return Json(lmasterRecords, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

DropDown boxs

Filter By Agent: 
                             
                                @Html.DropDownList("var1", null, new { @class = "form-control col-sm-3 " })

```
JqGrid Function




    script>
        $.noConflict();
        jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
            $("#jqGrid").jqGrid({
                url: '@Url.Action("Getlist")',
                datatype: 'json',
                mtype: 'Get',
                page: 1,
                postData: { id: $("#var1").val(), LstatusId: $("#var2").val(), AllDate: $("#AllData").attr("checked") ? true : false, DateFrom: $("#cmbSDate").val(), DateTo: $("#cmbTDate").val() },
                colModel: [
                         { label:'RecordID', hidden: true, name: 'RecordID', key: true, width: 75 },
                        { label: 'Name', name: 'Name', width: 200 },
                        { label: 'CityName', name: 'CityName', width: 110 },
                        { label: 'CountryName', hidden: true, name: 'CountryName', width: 150 },
                        { label: 'Address', hidden: true, name: 'Address', width: 150 },
                        { label: 'PhoneNo', hidden: true, name: 'PhoneNo', key: true, width: 75 },
                        { label: 'MobileNo', name: 'MobileNo', width: 110 },
                        { label: 'Email', name: 'Email', width: 200 },
                        { label: 'Fax', hidden: true, name: 'Fax', width: 150 },
                        { label: 'LeadDate', name: 'EnteryDate', width: 100 },
                         { label: 'ProfType', hidden: true, name: 'ProfType', width: 150 },
                        { label: 'LeadStatus', name: 'LeadStatus', key: true, width: 150 },
                        { label: 'Description', name: 'Description', width:110 },
                        { label: 'UnitTypeName', name: 'UnitTypeName', width: 150 },
                        { label: 'User_name', name: 'User_name', width: 150 },
                        { label: 'IsClose', name: 'IsClose', width: 50}],

                loadonce:true,
                viewrecords: true,
                width: 1050,
                height: 350,
                rowNum: 100,
                rowList: [10, 20, 30,50,100,500], 
                pager: "#jqGridPager"
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: Which **version** of jqGrid you use and from which **fork** of jqGrid ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), commercial [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or an old jqGrid in version <=4.7)? You use tags [jqgrid-asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jqgrid-asp.net/info) and [mvcjqgrid](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/mvcjqgrid/info) of *absolutely different products*.

Comment: i am using jqgrid in Asp.net mvc4  and i want to filter record not buit in filter . i am using dropdown list and fill dropdown from database.

Comment: oh commercial version i am changing free jqgrid please tell me how to filter record using Html dropdown .

Comment: Please answer on my previous question. It's important to know not the version of ASP.NET MVC, but **the version and the fork** of jqGrid, which you use (or can use). Where you get jqGrid. If you loaded it from NuGet, then I recommend you to use [free jqGrid](https://www.nuget.org/packages/free-jqGrid) 4.14.1 package.

Comment: Your current code just use `postData` parameters. It means that you send the information about the filter **during creating the grid**. jqGrid loads the data **once** and the data stays the same.

Comment: i am using free jqgrid which you have given a link . and i am using asp,net mvc4 version.

Comment: give me a sample of code which i understand how to give parameter and filter record.

Comment: i have upload image of form which i mension dropdown list and jqgrid.

Comment: You should more clear describe what you want to implement. Do you need to use **server side** filtering of data of **client side** filtering? The current code looks more like you want to use server side filtering, but you loads about 25000 rows. It is the total number of rows, which you could have? In general you can use client side filtering in the case. You can try for example the performance on [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/performane-15-60000-25-free-jqgrid.htm) with 60000 rows, 15 column and 25 rows on the page.

Comment: It's unclear for me from the image how the user should starts searching. Do you have something like "start search" button?

Comment: i want to filter records either server server side or client side my only focus to filter records ,and yes i loads 25000 rows ,its a total rows.

Comment: for the time forget about search text box . i want to filter record using dropdown list from jqgrid .How to do this ?

Comment: Sorry, but you should formulate your question more clear. Which dropdown you mean? `@Html.DropDownList("var1", null, new { @class = "form-control col-sm-3 " })` gives no information about the *content* of `<select>` element. Which column corresponds the dropdown? Moreover the definition of `colModel` contains clear error: you use `key: true` for more as one column. If the value of `RecordID` property, for example, different for every row then you should remove `key: true` from all other columns.

Comment: I suppose that what you need can be found in the demo https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/yvbt6w54/1/. You can add `stype: "select", searchoptions: { sopt: ["eq", "ne"], generateValue: true, noFilterText: "Any" }` in some columns (in `colModel`) and to call `filterToolbar` method to create the filter toolbar in jqGrid. The demo https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/yvbt6w54/1/ demonstrates additionally the usage of select2 or jQuery UI Autocomplete instead of simple `<select>`, but you can start with simple `<select>`. Compare columns Client, Tax and Shipped Via.

Comment: You can improve the performance of your grid by removing of all hidden columns and the usage of `additionalProperties` instead. It allows to save the properties locally inside of JavaScript objects, but not place the data on the DOM. I could write you more details later.

Comment: i don't want to use jqgrid tootbar , i am using Html dropdown

Comment: @Html.DropDownList("var1", null, new { @class = "form-control col-sm-3 " })  this is html.helper class which i am using in asp.net mvc4 var1 variable which come from controler and load dropdown list . data is load in in dropdown list.

Comment: What **content** have `   
@Html.DropDownList("var1", null, new { @class = "form-control col-sm-3 " }) `? Which relation it has to some column of jqGrid? You can of cause use external controls, but you will have to write more own code in the case. You should generate the **filter** in [the form](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:advanced_searching#options), which should used by jqGrid.

Comment: if you skype id i will show you a project then you will clearly understand what i am doing.

Comment: Sorry, but I have to do my main job. I help already other people in pauses in my job and in my free time. I do already many thing for other people for free, but I don't want to provide support via Skype additionally.

Comment: just for 5 mint only

Comment: tell me time when you are free.?